# Bootstrap datepicker get current format

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

Is it possible to get the current format applied to bootstrap datepicker from the bootstrap-datepicker object?

I have several datepickers with different formats and I'd like to get the format in each of them to apply different validation methods based on the current format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 3 solutions for you.

**Solution 1:** Declare `dateFormat` variable and use it on datepicker init or anywhere you want.

```
var dateFormat = 'mm/dd/yyyy';

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: dateFormat ,
    startDate: '-3d'
});
```

**Solution 2:** Declare `dateFormat` variable and use it on `$.fn.datepicker.defaults` to apply for all datepickers and use it anywhere you want.

```
var dateFormat = 'mm/dd/yyyy';
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = dateFormat;
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-3d'
});
```

**Solution 3:** Init datepicker by `data-date-format` in HTML and you can get it by `$("#datepicker").attr('data-date-format')`.

```js
console.log($("#datepicker").attr('data-date-format'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker" class="datepicker" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my answer to clarify my needs. Solution1 and Solution 2 are not good for me. Solution3 would work but I'd like to know if there is a possibility to read it directly from the object, instead having to add a mark in html

Comment: @xrodas I look around and I think we can't get the date format from the date-picker object directly. And on solutions 1 and 2, maybe your problem is the js is on different files? if yes, you can declare date format to `window.dateFormat = 'mm/dd/yyyy'` and you can use anywhere.

Comment: Once I see I can't get the format from the object, solution 3 is the best workaround for me